# TypeError: Cannot redefine property: tap

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

i'm receiving this error whenever i try to run `npm run dev`

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot redefine property: tap
at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\Themes\Storefront\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\helpers.js:21:8)
at Module._compile (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\Themes\Storefront\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\index.js:3:1)
at Module._compile (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
```

my package.json file

```
    "scripts": {
    "rtlcss": "rtlcss",
    "postinstall": "lerna bootstrap",
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress  --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-spatie": "^2.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.13",
    "laravel-mix-merge-manifest": "^0.1.2",
    "lerna": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss": "8.1",
    "rtlcss": "^2.4.0",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.5.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "schema-utils": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.24.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
}
```

a suggested solution on Laravel-mix github is to change versions but that didn't solve it for me. any reason for that error?

Comment: I got this error when I was importing 'laravel-mix' in tailwind.config.js