# webpack-cli: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: tap

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

i'm receiving this error whenever i try to run npm run dev

```
npm run development
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot redefine property: tap
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dell\Downloads\fay\Modules\Votes\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\helpers.js:21:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dell\Downloads\fay\Modules\Votes\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\index.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
```

My package.json

```
 "scripts": {
        "rtlcss": "rtlcss",
        "postinstall": "lerna bootstrap",
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
        "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
        "eslint": "^4.9.0",
        "eslint-config-spatie": "^2.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
        "glob": "^7.1.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.39",
        "laravel-mix-merge-manifest": "^0.1.2",
        "lerna": "^2.9.0",
        "rtlcss": "^2.4.0",
        "sass": "^1.25.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.5.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "yarn": "^1.22.19"
    }
}
```

a suggested solution on Laravel-mix github is to change versions but that didn't solve it for me. any reason for that error?

i also delete node_module and package_lock.json and again run
npm install
but it still same

Comment: if you have the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470320/typeerror-cannot-redefine-property-tap it's ok to ask again (since that's unanswered and old) but don't  copy the other question verbatim

Comment: Also [update your NPM scripts to work with Laravel mix 6](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade#update-your-npm-scripts)

Comment: and i try your solution but it still not working can you suggest me more

Comment: npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
> development
> mix        

[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot redefine property: tap
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dell\Downloads\fay\Modules\Votes\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\helpers.js:21:8)

Comment: i am sorry i don't mean to copy you i face the same problem so i post it. i don't want to offend anyone

Comment: Try removing `"webpack": "^5.74.0",` and then deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and running `npm install` again as well

Comment: I had two node_modules folders in your project. So it was loading two different versions of laravel mix. Removing the other folder fixed the issue.

Comment: [webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot redefine property: tap
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/virtual/vps-e25466/2/2c563f2522/staging.pnutso.                                                                                                             com/Themes/Storefront/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:5:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)

Comment: hey, i try every solution you give but still getting error and also using "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0"